# Products request crash in Swift language

Tags: ios, swift, skproduct

I have this code to handle in app purchase's

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

class iap: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate,SKPaymentTransactionObserver {


    var productsArray = Array<SKProduct>()
    var product: SKProduct?

    override init()
    {
        super.init()

        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
             print("starting IAPS")
            let productIdentifiers = Set(["com.blabla.bla.pro"])
            let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as Set<String>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        } else {
            print("please enable IAPS")
        }
    }

    // 1
    var list = [SKProduct]()
    var p = SKProduct()

    // 2
    func buyProduct() {
        print("buy " + p.productIdentifier)
        let pay = SKPayment(product: p)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment)
    }

    //3
    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
        print("product request")
        let myProduct = response.products

        for product in myProduct {
            print("product added")
            print(product.productIdentifier)
            print(product.localizedTitle)
            print(product.localizedDescription)
            print(product.price)

            list.append(product )
        }


    }

    // 4
    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        print("transactions restored")

        for transaction in queue.transactions {
            let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction

            let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

            switch prodID {
            case "com.blabla.bla.pro":
                print("pro upgrade update only basic stuff futher updates must be payed")


            default:
                print("IAP not setup")
            }

        }
    }

    // 5
    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        print("add paymnet")

        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
            print(trans.error)

            switch trans.transactionState {

            case .Purchased:
                print("buy, ok unlock iap here")
                print(p.productIdentifier)

                let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String
                switch prodID {
                case "com.blabla.bla.pro":
                    print("pro upgrade update only basic stuff futher updates must be payed")


                default:
                    print("IAP not setup")
                }

                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break;
            case .Failed:
                print("buy error")
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break;
            default:
                print("default")
                break;

            }
        }
    }

    // 6
    func finishTransaction(trans:SKPaymentTransaction)
    {
        print("finish trans")
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(trans)
    }

    //7
    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, removedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])
    {
        print("remove trans");
    }

}
```

And when a view is loaded I call the iap class:

```
class test: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let inAppPurchase = iap()

    }
}
```

The call works, but the only thing I see is starting iaps, than it crashes with this error: message sent to deallocated instance.

And this is the result when I log with zombies.
[image]

I have tried everything, but with this error as result. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your iap class is getting released when you go out of scope, after you make the request. Store it in a property to keep it alive:

```
class test: UITabBarController {

    let inAppPurchase = iap()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it and makes no difference. (I have added your code in my question)

Comment: I feel so stupid right know, it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: No worries. Might help to give the Swift guide book a re-read.

Comment: One more question, why was it crashing? Was it because the system was busy with the iap class, and the view did load releases it to go to the next block?

Comment: You set your iap class the SKProductRequest delegate, made a request, and then released the class (since you were not maintaining a strong reference to it). When an object has 0 strong references, ARC releases it. The crash occurred when the SKProductRequest tried to call a method on your released class.